# WooCommerce hide order item meta from front end (not admin)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I have a couple of order item meta details that I would not like the customer to see (on the view orders page under account info). I have found a filter that will remove this data from the ADMIN (where I would still like to see it), but can't find a similar filter to remove it from the FRONT END (where it should be hidden).

Here is the code that will (uselessly, for me) remove it from the back end admin:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 'add_hidden_order_items' );
function add_hidden_order_items( $order_items ) {
    $order_items[] = 'paid_already';
    $order_items[] = 'variation_sku';
    // and so on...
    return $order_items;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it ended up being much easier than I was supposing, the template actually already puts out a class with the name of my item meta, so I just hid it in the css like so:

```
.order_details .variation-variation_sku, .order_details .variation-paid_already {
    display: none !important;
}
```

While it would be nice to know how to prevent these item meta from ever being output, I can live with this as a solution.

Answer (score 18):

Save the values with an underscore prefix, that way it won't be displayed, just saved. Like so:

```
$item->add_meta_data('_hidden_field', '123', true);
```

Comment: This should be the best answer; it's simple and effective.

Comment: Best one. Thanks

Comment: Work fine thx !

Answer (score 6):

```
//remove order item meta key
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 'mobilefolk_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 10, 1 );

function mobilefolk_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data($formatted_meta){
    $temp_metas = [];
    foreach($formatted_meta as $key => $meta) {
        if ( isset( $meta->key ) && ! in_array( $meta->key, [
                'lyric_id',
                'lyric_song_title',
                'lyric_artist_name'
            ] ) ) {
            $temp_metas[ $key ] = $meta;
        }
    }
    return $temp_metas;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I insert my explain in my code. Now I think its very useful. I have to search many times but I can not find anyone give good solution. My solution can solve problem for every plugins that use order item meta key.

Comment: This is a good answer! I want to save the key (don't want to use underscore that is), but avoid displaying it to the customer in the My Accounts page!

Answer (score 3):

use " _ " before order item meta meta_key it will be hide automatically

Answer (score 2):

if you want to hide some items meta from front end order view, you will need to override 
`order-details-item.php` woocommerce template file.

I recommend you: [**Overriding woocommerce templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) method, copying templates woocommerce folder to your active theme (or child theme better) and renaming it "woocommerce".
Once copied in that woocommerce folder (inside your active theme), you will find `order-details-item.php` in `order` subfolder.

In line 36 of `order-details-item.php` you will find this:

```
            $order->display_item_meta( $item );
            $order->display_item_downloads( $item );
```

You can change this adding a conditional like:

```
            if ( $item != 'paid_already' || $item != 'variation_sku') {
                $order->display_item_meta( $item );
                $order->display_item_downloads( $item );
            }
```

I am not sure of the veracity of this conditional and can't test it. You may be obliged to change it a bit…

just for information, function **display_item_meta()** works this way:

```
/**
 * Display meta data belonging to an item.
 * @param  array $item
 */
public function display_item_meta( $item ) {
    $product   = $this->get_product_from_item( $item );
    $item_meta = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item, $product );
    $item_meta->display();
}
```

References:

- [WC Template: `templates/order/order-details-item.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details-item.php)
- [Overriding woocommerce templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)
- [display_item_meta()](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1342-1350) in [Class WC_Abstract_Order](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried it and it did not hide those items on the order page (and it threw no errors in the logs either).

Comment: $item is an array, and while I can find my keys in the array, I can't seem to get it to output the array just ignoring my two keys. Not sure if there is a way to do what I want without writing a new for loop here...

Comment: I ended up solving this another way, but upvoted your answer anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with item meta data, I'm simply hiding the item meta data from the cart using CSS:

```
.wc-item-meta {display:none;}
```