# Display custom order item metadata only on WooCommerce admin orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

To display custom  data , I use this hook 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item'. He works good. But it displays data in three places - in the admin panel (in order), in the order details and in the personal account. I need the data to be displayed only in the admin panel. how to do it?
My code

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'wdm_add_custom_order_line_item_meta', 10, 4 );

function wdm_add_custom_order_line_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'file', $values ) ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $permfile = $values['file'];
        $basePath = plugin_base_url();
        $fileid = $permfile;
        ....
        $item->add_meta_data('File','<button >  <a href="'.$fileid.'" download>' . Download.   '</a></button>');
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following to display a custom download button on admin order items only *(code is commented)*:

```
// Save custom order item meta
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_custom_order_item_meta', 10, 4 );
function save_custom_order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset($values['file']) && ! empty($values['file']) ) {
        // Save it in an array to hide meta data from admin order items
        $item->add_meta_data('file', array( $values['file'] ) );
    }
}

// Get custom order item meta and display a linked download button
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'display_admin_order_item_custom_button', 10, 3 );
function display_admin_order_item_custom_button( $item_id, $item, $product ){
    // Only "line" items and backend order pages
    if( ! ( is_admin() && $item->is_type('line_item') ) )
        return;

    $file_url = $item->get_meta('file'); // Get custom item meta data (array)

    if( ! empty($file_url) ) {
        // Display a custom download button using custom meta for the link
        echo '<a href="' . reset($file_url) . '" class="button download" download>' . __("Download", "woocommerce") . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

The custom download button is only displayed in admin order items.

[image]

Comment: Be aware that meta deta would be visible in order confirmation page.
To hide this meta item use _ before its name. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596481/woocommerce-hide-order-item-meta-from-front-end-not-admin